# New wireless router works fine on other devices. Ubuntu connects but will not send/receive after 0 to 10 hours

Tags: wireless

Network Manager says it's connected but no send/receive possible.  Usually, a manual disconnect/connect will enable transmission for a while, but it always fails after 0 to 10 hours.  I ran the script
    wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info
and uploaded the result to http://paste.ubuntu.com/24494753/
Any help appreciated!

Note:  Broadcom internal wireless appears not to be functional.
Note:  I used the power management approach and it seemed to work for about 6 hours, but then the USB wireless exhibited the earlier behavior.

Comment: Why are you using the USB wireless instead of the internal Broadcom? I'd much rather troubleshoot without the USB.

Comment: See if `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` helps any with the USB